# how to extract text from selenium webelement icon with hovertext

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using amazon for an example, say I want to extract the star rating for a product. Hovering over the stars shows a text element "4.0 out of 5 stars", and upon inspection shows:

```
<span class="a-icon-alt">4.0 out of 5 stars</span>
```

Typically using selenium with python, I would select the text in this element by using a css selector, then getting the .text - but for some reason it returns blank.

```
    review_list = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]')
    review_block = review_list.find_elements_by_xpath('*')
    for parts in review_block:
        print("rating = " + parts.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a-icon-alt").text)
```

Comment: Maybe the text doesn't exist until you hover over the element.

Comment: thanks Greg, so I wouldn't be able to just extract the string inside the <span class="a-icon-alt">4.0 out of 5 stars</span> ?

Comment: You can extract that text, but you might need to hover over the element *first* and then extract the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, apparently the element is not stored as .text and i need to use get_element('innerHTML')

The following code was able to grab the star ratings off amazon:

```
review_list = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cm_cr-review_list"]')
review_block = review_list.find_elements_by_xpath('*')
for parts in review_block:
    print("rating = " + parts.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a-icon-alt").get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```